# jsPlumb .NET library/Orchard CMS Workflow

Tags: orchardcms, jsplumb

I'm interested in using jsPlumb to create a workflow designer. It looks like all jQuery, so I'm assuming I'd have to write the plumbing (excuse the pun) to persist changes to connections and write out the XML corresponding to a workflow definition to the design canvas.

Question #1 - is there a .NET library out there for jsPlumb?
Question #2 - I watched this done in a steering committee meeting for Orchard CMS. Is the Orachd team already doing this? Should I just wait for 1.7 and look at the source code?

Comment: Yes, this is already done. Just clone the 1.x branch. it's there.

Comment: Where? I downloaded the Orchard 1.6 source code and did two separate searchs for "jsplumb" and "workflow". No hits. When you say clone the .x branch, what are you referring to?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it, thanks!